# Grab IMG source from HTML link

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this HTML code that I took from IMDB.

```
<img alt="Johnny Depp" height="209" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM0ODU5Nzk2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzI2ODgyNQ@@._V1_UY209_CR3,0,140,209_AL_.jpg" width="140">
```

My question is how can I get the link of the image with `<img src=`,so the result will be:

```
"<img src="https://m.mediaamazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM0ODU5Nzk2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzI2ODgyNQ@@._V1_UY209_CR3,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For parsing or scraping from URL, you need to add [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) library.

Add the dependency in your gradle file.

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:latest_version'
```

Then you can write a method to connect and get the HTML code.

```
private String getHTMLCode() {
try {
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yourURL.com/").get();
  Element imageElement = document.select("img").first();
  
  String absoluteUrl = imageElement.absUrl("src");  //absolute URL on src
  String srcValue = imageElement.attr("src");  // exact content value of the attribute. 

  } catch (IOException e) {
  //For getting error print error in LOG
  Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
  Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
  
  Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load HTML code",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

For further documentation you can get help from the [official site.](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document)

Comment: Thanks for replay,I am getting some detection errors:
https://ibb.co/4thm5ZM

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
            Element imageElement = document.select("img").first();
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable document
  location: class MainActivity